# Matlab function to determine if a function is continous or not?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I wish to write code for Riemann Stieltjes integrals using MATLAB's Symbolic Math toolbox. A necessary condition for the theorem to hold is that the function's derivative must be continuous. I am using the `diff` function to find the symbolic derivative. The domain of the function is a closed real interval containing infinitely many points, so I can't check at each and every point. I want to know if there are any built-in functions in MATLAB that determine if a function is continuous or not.

Is there any way I can check if the function obtained by differentiating my input function is continuous?

Comment: That's basic calculus.  There are three criteria that a function needs to satisfy if it is deemed continuous: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-determine-whether-a-function-is-continuous.html.  That link only shows it for one point.  If you want to illustrate that a function is continuous, you must test the above three criteria over the entire domain of your function.  BTW, this is off-topic here.  Consider asking this at Mathematics StackExchange: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The domain of the function is a closed real interval containing infinitely many points, so I can't check at each and every point.I just want to know if there is any inbuilt function in MATLAB which determines whether the function is continuous or not.

Comment: @rayryeng: See the updated question. I don't think the OP is asking the off-topic question about the math of determining if a function is continuous or not. And there is a built-in function in MuPAD to help one do exactly this.

Comment: @horchler - Now that I see the update, you are correct.  With that, I'll retract my vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a way via [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html)'s [`discont`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/discont.html) function, which lists the discontinuities of a function. MuPAD functions can be [called from within Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html). For example:

```
syms x;
f = 1/(x*(x-1));
feval(symengine,'discont',f,x)
```

returns `[ 1, 0]`, the two poles of `f`. If you want to bound your search domain, one way to do so is via [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-1.html). Now:

```
syms x;
assume(x>=0);
assumeAlso(x<1/2);
f = 1/(x*(x-1));
feval(symengine,'discont',f,x)
```

just returns `0`. Or, you can use MuPAD's string notation:

```
syms x;
f = 1/(x*(x-1));
feval(symengine,'discont',f,[char(x) '=0.5..2'])
```

which returns `1`. Obviously if the list of discontinuities over a domain in not empty (see [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html)), then the function is not continuous (i.e., discontinuous).

I recommend reading the documentation for `discont`. I have no idea how reliable it is or if it will have trouble with more complex functions.